# Result of CGI script on the same page

Tags: python, cgi

For example, I have html page:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="http://127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/test.py" method="post" target="_blank">
            PRESS BUTTON TO TEST PYTHON CGI
            <br><input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And Python CGI script (test.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "Content-type: text/html"
print
print "<html><head><title>CGI</title></head>"
print "<body>"
print "hello cgi"
print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

So, when I press button, it will open NEW page with results of script ('hello cgi')
How can I output 'hello cgi' on the same page with button? (not new page!)

Thanks for help.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Finally, I decided to use AJAX.

Python:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
import cgi
str = 'hello from cgi!'
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print "%s" % str
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Simple Ajax Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function xmlhttpPost(strURL) {
    var xmlHttpReq = false;
    var self = this;
    // Mozilla/Safari
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        self.xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    // IE
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        self.xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    self.xmlHttpReq.open('POST', strURL, true);
    self.xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    self.xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (self.xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) {
            updatepage(self.xmlHttpReq.responseText);
        }
    }
    self.xmlHttpReq.send(getquerystring());
}

function getquerystring() {
    var form     = document.forms['f1'];
    var word = form.word.value;
    qstr = encodeURI(word);
    return qstr;
}

function updatepage(str){
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = str;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="f1">
  <input value="Submit" type="button" onclick='JavaScript:xmlhttpPost("http://127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/test.py")'></p>
  <div id="result"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```